# Numpy local maximas in one dimension of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to find the local maximas of a 2D array but only in one dimension. Ie:

```
1 2 3 2 1 1 4 5 6 2 
2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2
1 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

would return:

```
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Obviously this is trivial to solve by iterating through the array, but this is slow and usually avoidable. Is there a fast way of achieving this?

Edit: 
I've devised a faster solution:

import numpy as np

```
testArray = np.array([[1,2,3,2,1,1,4,5,6,2],[2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2],[1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3] ])

leftShift = np.roll(testArray,1, axis=1)
rightShift = np.roll(testArray,-1, axis=1)

Max = ((testArray>leftShift) & (testArray>rightShift) )*1

print(Max)
```

Which returns:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

This is the right result except for repeated readings. Ie.. what differentiates "13331" (maxima) from "13333789" (stationary point)

Comment: did you test how slow it is ?

Comment: Yes, 0.8 seconds for one image

Comment: The answer actually depends on the data you have in hand. How many of the same min values are on average within one data set (image) and what is the data set (image) size?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by applying finite difference gradient to each row and check sign change.
However it is not clear what to do at the boundaries.